# How to retain Angular Controller's scope values in Android?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, scope, internal-storage

I just want to store my scope values in android internal memory. Because I loose all ListItems when I restart the application. Is there any way to retain all controller's scope values?

My controller:

```
App.controller('MessageCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.title = "My Title";
   $scope.items;
   if($scope.items == undefined || $scope.items == []){
    console.log("Empty items found");
    $scope.items = [];
   }
   $scope.number = '';
   $scope.message = '';

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        console.log('Adding Item..');
          $scope.items.push({
              number: $scope.number,
              message: $scope.message
          });
    };

    $scope.deleteItem = function(index){
      console.log("Deleting item - "+index);
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    };
}]);
```

List View:

```
<ion-list class="list" show-delete="shouldShowDelete">
              <ion-item class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="item in items">
                 <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="deleteItem($index)"></ion-delete-button>
                 <img src="img/default_avatar.png">
                 <h2>{{item.number}}</h2>
                 <p>{{item.message}}</p>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-toggle ng-model="shouldShowDelete">
                Show Delete?
              </ion-toggle>
          </ion-list>
```

I want to retain $scope.items array. so that I can render the List when user restart the application.

Any suggestion will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can have look at the local storage options provided by cordova, which stores the data even after the application exits.
The link to cordova local storage [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)